# VBA: Inputting variable in formula not working

Tags: vba, variables, match, formula

I'm trying to use the Index+Match formula in VBA.  For the arrays, I would like to find their address by using .Find, then saving their address and using that in the formula.

The error I get with the code below is "Application-defined or object-Defined error" for the formula.

Can someone shed some light on why this is happening? Also, if anyone knows how to select the entire column that c is found instead of the cell that would be an additional great help!

```
Sub Find()

With Worksheets("User").Range("A1:BZ1")
    Set c = .Find("userRole", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
    End If
End With

With Worksheets("User").Range("A1:BZ1")
    Set c = .Find("name", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        secondAddress = c.Address
    End If
End With


Workbooks("Internal_Master").Sheets("Client").Range("C2").Formula = "=Index([" & firstAddress & "],Match(Client!B2,[" & secondAddress & "],0)"
```

There are two sheets: "Client" and "User"
The arrays are coming from the "User" sheet, and the formula is being used in the "Client" sheet

Comment: On what line does the error occur? Do you declare all variables?

Comment: @DavidG The error occurs on the last line where the formula is

Comment: I suggest to first write and debug the formula in Excel. After then you can try to create it from VBA. work *step-by-step*; your formula's syntax is messy.

Comment: As A.S.H stated: go step by step here. Save each value in a separate variable and check those values. Break down the last line into the smallest logical steps, and test each step for errors.

Answer (score 0):

1.Write this before the formula:

```
  debug.print  "=Index([" & firstAddress & "],Match(Client!B2,[" & secondAddress & "],0)"
```

2.Take a look at the immediate window.

3.Analyze the result it a bit and think where you can improve it.

4.Probably - remove the "[" and "]" parenthesis.